# Self hosted Drone CI doesn't synchronize my commits with Github

Tags: github, docker, continuous-integration, drone.io

I have a self hosted Drone CI that runs in Docker.  I set it up using the image https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mattgruter/drone/ and it's up and running just fine.  I've connected my Github account and sync'd my repos.  However after I added my .drone.yml file to a repo, it's not synchronizing with my Drone CI.  Drone just says "Add a .drone.yml file and make a commit to trigger a build".  Not sure what I'm missing.

My .drone.yml just looks like this.  I'm just starting to use Drone for the first time, so not sure if I've missed something in this file.  I assume the image is a docker image.

```
image: maven/maven:3.3.3-jdk-8-onbuild
name: maps
script:
  - mvn clean install
```

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the webhook to me. Check the settings of your GitHub repository. Under webhooks; can you verify that the last delivery was successful?

Comment: Ok, so looks like they're all timing out.  I should have probably specified that my Drone CI is on my internal network.  Is there no way to have it periodically poll my repository for changes rather than receiving requests from Github?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, no. I could imagine that it's possible to write a small script that polls the repo and triggers the webhook from within your own network. Other than that, I'd keep an eye out for the 0.4 release, which should have improved support for plugins. Not sure if that would allow you to do something similar, but might be worth looking into.